# What does it mean for a Markov CHAIN to be recurrent (not just a state)?

Tags: markov-process, recurrent-events

There are many resources offering equivalent definitions of recurrence for a *state* in a Markov Chain - for example, state $x$ is *recurrent* if, starting in state $x$ you will eventually return to state $x$ almost surely.
However, I have been asked to show that a certain *Markov Chain* is recurrent. Half an hour of Google searching has not been able to answer whether this means *existence* of a recurrent state, or that *all* states are recurrent.

So I put it to the community - what does it mean for a *Markov Chain* to be recurrent?

Comment: If a chain is irreducible (has only one class of intercommunicating states) and any one of the states is recurrent, then one can show that all are recurrent and the chain is called recurrent.

Comment: BruceET's comment answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

If a chain is irreducible (has only one class of intercommunicating states) and any one of the states is recurrent, then one can show that all are recurrent and the chain is called recurrent.

Consider the three-state chain with transition matrix $\mathbf{P}$ entered into R below. I will show some computations in R that may be relevant
to this questions and to your further study of Markov Chains.

```
P = matrix(c(0.5, 0.5,   0,
             0.5,   0, 0.5,
               0, 0.5, 0.5), nrow = 3, byrow=T)
P 
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.5  0.5  0.0
[2,]  0.5  0.0  0.5
[3,]  0.0  0.5  0.5
```

In R, matrix multiplication is indicated as `%*%`. We find the 2-step transition matrix $\mathbf{P}^2.$  Because all entries are positive, it is clear that all states
intercommunicate.

```
P2 = P %*% P;  P2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.50 0.25 0.25
[2,] 0.25 0.50 0.25
[3,] 0.25 0.25 0.50
```

As the power of the transition matrix increases, the rows become more similar:

```
 P4 = P2 %*% P2;  P4
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
[1,] 0.3750 0.3125 0.3125
[2,] 0.3125 0.3750 0.3125
[3,] 0.3125 0.3125 0.3750

P8 = P4 %*% P4;  P8
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
 [1,] 0.3359375 0.3320312 0.3320312
 [2,] 0.3320312 0.3359375 0.3320312
 [3,] 0.3320312 0.3320312 0.3359375
```

Eventually, each row converges to the steady state vector $\sigma= (1/3, 1/3, 1/3),$ indicating that over the long run, the chain is in each state about $1/3$ of the time:  $\sigma\mathbf{P} = \sigma.$

This is an 'ergodic' chain. Its limiting distribution is the same as its steady state distribution.

This particular chain has a *doubly-stochastic*
transition matrix $\mathbf{P};$ each *column* sums to $1.$ If the transition matrix is doubly stochastic, then in the long run each state is equally likely.

More generally, one can use eigen vectors to find
the stationary distribution of an ergodic chain.
Because R finds right eigen vectors, and we want
a left eigen vector, we use the transpose of the
transition matrix, denoted `t(P)` below:

```
g = eigen(t(A))
sg = as.numeric(g$vec[,1])
 # 1st col of vector output is vector you want
 # 'as.numeric' gets rid of any complex-nr notation

sg = sg/sum(sg)  # scale so elements add to 1
sg
[1] 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
sg %*% A  # check
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
```